# Eclipse Indigo : Jobs found still running after platform shutdown

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse indigo. When I try to run a configuration it says `Jobs found still running after platform shutdown. Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled then during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.IDEWorkbenchActivityHelper`

I tried the following

```
rm MY_WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap
rm MY_WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi
```

But those files are not present itself but I am able to do the following

```
 rm MY_WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workbench.xml
```

Even after deleting that when I restart the eclipse and run the previous configuration, I am getting the same error. I also tried the following

```
eclipse -clearPersistedState
```

Still no luck. How will I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

`eclipse -clean -clearPersistedState` option did not work for me( version 3.8.0). I have created new eclipse 'Run configuration' and worked.

Answer (score 0):

That is not an error for you to fix as a user. As it says, it's up to the plug-in that scheduled the background job to end it. You should, though, at least see if it's already resolved in Luna SR1 (soon SR2) rather than Indigo, the 2011 release.